# postgresql create function with multiple IF ELSE condition

Tags: sql, database, function, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am creating a function in postgresql which will do something like following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_label_id_exist(_labelid integer, OUT result text) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    SELECT pkid FROM table_1 WHERE label_id = _labelid;
    IF FOUND THEN
    result := 'true';
    RETURN;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
    SELECT pkid FROM table_2 WHERE label_id = _labelid;
    IF FOUND THEN
    result := 'true';
    RETURN;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
    SELECT pkid FROM table_3 WHERE label_id = _labelid;
    IF FOUND THEN
    result := 'true';
    RETURN;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
    result := 'false';

    RETURN;
END
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

Here the function looks for data in `table_1` first. If no data then it will go to next table and so on. If any of the table has data it will break the condition and return true else finally it will return false. I think the code that I have written here is not correct. Please help to achieve my goal.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Union could be a good idea. But I am not good on that. But obviously I would like to try. Can you please give me a sample. I just want to return true or false. If there have any result for any of the queries it will return true otherwise false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be a simpler way of doing what you're are trying to do with less code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_label_id_exist(_labelid integer, OUT result text) as

$BODY$
 BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_1 WHERE label_id = _labelid limit 1) THEN

        result := 'true';

    ELSEIF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_2 WHERE label_id = _labelid limit 1) THEN

        result := 'true';

    ELSEIF EXISTS(SELECT 1 from table_3 WHERE label_id = _labelid limit 1) THEN

        result := 'true';

    ELSE

        result := 'false';
    END IF;

    RETURN;
END
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thanks Juan, Pretty impressively simpler way. Only I did some correction in the code to satisfy my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_label_id_exist(_labelid integer,
    OUT result text) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    SELECT pkid FROM table_1 WHERE label_id = _labelid;
    IF FOUND THEN
        result := 'true';
        RETURN;
    end if;

    SELECT pkid FROM table_2 WHERE label_id = _labelid;
    IF FOUND THEN
        result := 'true';
        RETURN;
    end if;

    SELECT pkid FROM table_3 WHERE label_id = _labelid;
    IF FOUND THEN
        result := 'true';
        RETURN;
    end if;
    result := 'false';
    RETURN;
END
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```